# getting input value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular.js and i have been having trouble getting form input value.

So i have looked for an answer all over including stackoverflow  i could not find any answer.

I want to get the input values using the controller but on each attempt i try i get in the console that its undefined on just using either an object or just text

here is the javascript code:

```
$scope.url = '';
            $scope.user = {
                    password    : '',
                    repassword  : ''
                };

            $scope.registerUser = function()
            {
                $log.info($scope.email);
                $log.info($scope.user);
            }
```

here is the html code:

```
<table class="table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        <form class="form-inline" action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="email">E-mail</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="email">
                            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-value="user.password"><td>
                </tr>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="Repassword">Reenter Password:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" class="form-control" name="Repassword" ng-value="user.repassword"></td>
                </tr>
            </div>
            <tr><td><input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Register" ng-click="registerUser()"></td></tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: could it be because you are using `ng-value` instead of `ng-model`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please accept the answer that has worked for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `ng-value` instead of `ng-model`:

```
<input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
<input type="password" ng-model="user.repassword">
```

You might also want to pass in `user` to your `ng-click` for convenience and less typing in the function:

```
ng-click="registerUser(user)"

$scope.registerUser = function(user) {
  console.log(user);
}
```

Comment: @Rob It makes for less typing in the function, so I usually do it anyways.

Comment: @JohnMuchoki Glad to hear, don't forget to mark it as the answer :)